# Why does Captain Marvel in the MCU not have her sash?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, captain-marvel

Captain Marvel (Carol Danvers) as quite a famous look which sports a sash. For example, we see this in *Captain Marvel Vol. 8* Issue 6 where her look is the basis for her look in the MCU.

[image: Captain Marvel in space with her sash]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

However, her look in *Captain Marvel* and *Avengers: Endgame* does not include the sash. Instead her uniform has a red belt across it in place of the sash.

[image: Captain Marvel on Earth without her sash]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It has also been revealed by [Andy Park on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BwpZEqbASHs/?utm_source=ig_embed&utm_campaign=dlfix) that he did do concept art for Carol with a sash on her uniform.

> See! I did try a sash option for Captain Marvel (& this is just one of many I attempted). For the record I fully support the directors decision not to have it for her solo debut film. Maybe in the future? ;)
>
> [image: Captain Marvel concept art with the sash]
> <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

**Why didn't Captain Marvel have the sash on her uniform?** Why did the directors choose to remove it?

Comment: Too similar to a cape, perhaps. Remember what happened to Dollar Bill?

Comment: Whilst I don't normally ask for explanations for DVs I'm not sure why this is getting some. Her sash is pretty iconic in the comics so it seems odd to not include it. It's one of the few things that she's had for quite a while despite costume changes. Anyone want to explain why they've downvoted? (Although I respect your right not to if you don't want to.)

Comment: During development of Captain Marvel 2 they should probably look at her costume [again one time](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qz2bOXLEvuE).

Comment: Probably it was downvoted, because the answer is already contained in the question: „directors decisiob...“

Comment: @TorstenLink That's the reason but not the why if that makes sense. The question is __why__ did they decide not to include it.

Comment: So the question should read: why did the directors decide to not include the sash, I think then the downvoted would be taken away...

Comment: @TorstenLink I think the original wording is fine for the intent but I've added that on the end to clear it up.

Comment: It is possible the directors decided that the sash would make her look more 'feminine'; i.e. less badass. Also, in the movie, CM's costume is a standard military uniform with non-standard colors. Maybe they thought a sash wouldn't make sense in a star soldier uniform.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen The first is certainly a possibility though I doubt it. The latter probably isn't considering the members of Starforce under Yon-Rogg all have different uniforms tailored to the individual so it's not quite a standard uniform.

Comment: Maybe it can be [caught in an impeller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4R2aW03pwL0)?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Per the answer below, the official explanation is exactly that a sash doesn't make sense in a Starforce soldier uniform.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Right but that's a slightly different point to what you was making because her uniform is ___not___ a standard one. It's based off of a standard one but is tailored, more so than just the colours.

Comment: The point is that NONE of the Starforce uniforms (whether standard or tailored) have sashes because they are impractical.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen And I agree with your point and that, that is the reason they didn't add them as I found the answer myself. I'm just saying that the uniforms are tailored to the individual so your point about it being a standard uniform is not correct and so it was still possible she could have had it.

Comment: @LethalCarrot: Okay, I accept the nitpick - and congratulations for finding the right answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After having a look around and flicking through various books I have found that this is answered in *Marvel's Captain Marvel: The Art Of The Movie*. In it Andy Park says that because her uniform is that of a Starforce member and a soldier it didn't make sense to have the sash. He relates that it would be very impractical and that there would have to be a story reason to have it so the directors and producers decided to scrap it. The book also includes quite a lot of concept art with Carol wearing a sash.

> "When we look at the comic, one of the iconic things about Captain Marvel's design is her sash," Park says. "In the comic book world, you can take a lot of artistic license with character design because it's all about the graphic read of the visual. That's why you give super heroes capes, because it looks cool. Because if they're flying, it can flow in the wind. But as *The Incredibles* has taught us, capes are very impractical. That's a human reality. Having capes and having things flowing when you're trying to fight enemies is very impractical because not only can you get it caught on things, your enemy can use that against you as well. So even though I did explore her having a sash - or just something flowing from her belt - at the end of the day, **knowing in the story that she's a soldier in the military, the directors and producers ultimately thought it didn't make sense. There would have to be a story reason why she would be wearing a sash, or something flowing like that, and there wasn't.**"

[image: Page from the book quoted above including some concept art images of Carol with her sash]

Comment: What's the difference between those four pictures (apart from her hair in the last one)?

Comment: @Bergi The differences are subtle. They're all in the head: https://imgur.com/a/0qburk4

Comment: @KevinJohnson, yep.  Check out the chin & eyes of the mask.

Comment: @Bergi pixel 73 has 25% more hue, are you blind?

Comment: That's a great "spot the difference" game right there! :D

Comment: Given that pretty well every officer's dress uniform on the planet has a sash of some form, that's some rather odd reasoning.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I think you've answered your own comment. _"**officer's dress** uniform"_ - she's not an officer and it isn't a dress uniform.